# What does the tilde/squiggly mean here: $\sum_{j\sim 1} A_{1,j} v_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, notation

I'm reading through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00847.pdf), and in Lemma 2.3 on page 4 they use a notation I am unfamiliar with. They say for $(m\times m)$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with eigenvector value at the first index, $v_1$ that

$$\Bigg|\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf{A}_{1,j} v_j\Bigg| = \Bigg|\sum_{j \sim 1} \mathbf{A}_{1,j} v_j\Bigg|$$

What does the $\sim$ symbol mean here?

[Edit:] fixed paper link (again)

[Edit:] More info: $\mathbf{A}$ is not exactly an adjacency matrix in the traditional sense. It is a symmetrical $(m\times m)$ matrix whose entries are all in $\{-1,0,1\}$

Comment: The link does not work. Even your sentence makes no sense to me ... "with eigenvector value at the first index"??

Comment: The link is available only to subscribers. This isn't going to work. I suggest you read the paper carefully to see if they've defined their unusual notation. And please clarify that phrase I already commented on.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the broken link. And @TedShifrin I'm not sure it's pertinent to the notation, but I mean given an eigenvector $\lambda_1$, the first value of that vector is denoted $v_1$.

Comment: My bad, found an arxiv version that isn't behind a paywall. The page number/lemma number is still the same

Comment: For example, it would have been useful to tag this with graph theory, and mention graph theory in the question, maybe even note $A$ is an adjacency matrix (if that is what it is.)  Notation is highly dependent on context, and graph theory is an important context.

Comment: Mentioning graph theory will help select potential answerers who can read the paper enough to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen the notation before, but it looks to me like adjacency of vertices (but at the level of indices, that is, $i\sim j$ if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent in $H$).

In particular, the last inequality in the displayed math from Lemma 2.3 requires that the number of $j$ with $j\sim 1$ is at most the maximum degree $\Delta(H)$, and the equality in the OP holds if $j\not\sim 1$ implies $A_{1,j}=0$ (or $v_j=0$, but we have no control over this).

Comment: (Thank you for linking the arXiv version!)

Comment: This makes sense to me, and it seems to make the lemma work too! (PS $v_j$ can't be 0 since its defined as the value in the eigenvector with the greatest absolute value, so that would imply $\lambda = \mathbf{0}$)

Comment: @Zaya: Well, $v_1$ cannot be zero, but it's imaginable that *some* coordinates of the eigenvector are zero— at least to me, although I know nothing serious about SGT.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I forgot it's not just using that particular coord at that point, it uses the whole thing.